# Console.log(json) returns complete message but res.status(200).json(json) is empty

Tags: node.js, express

In my Express app, the response from a POST request to `/keepAlive` returns an empty JSON. However, when I print in the same variable in the console, I see the value.

This is what I see in the console:

```
{ 
    status: 'ok',
    code: '0',
    msg: 'Keepalive procesado correctamente.',
    ops: [ 
        op1: { 
            op: 'upsertuser',
            params: [Array],
            created: 2019-07-19T16:12:39.000Z 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

And this is what I see in Postman:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "code": "0",
    "msg": "Keepalive procesado correctamente.",
    "ops": []
}
```

This is my code in Node.js:

```
app.post('/keepAlive', middleware.checkToken, function(req, res) {
    keepAlive(req, res, function(opsvar) {
        var json = {
            status: 'ok',
            code: '0',
            msg: 'Keepalive procesado correctamente.',
            ops: opsvar
        };

        console.log(json);
        res.status(200).json(json);
    })
})
```

Comment: It's possible that the elements in `opsvar` are not serializable to JSON. Based on the log output, it seems like they aren't plain old JavaScript objects. Do you know how those objects are being constructed?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own mistake, the problem was that I initialized the variable opsvar as an array and it had to be initialized as an Object.